# Unexpected end of input error in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to do a simple join in BigQuery.  Have not used it in a couple years (rusty) so probably just a tiny error in my syntax.  It is Standard SQL.

```
SELECT 
fiscal_week_of_year,
sum(quantity) as units_ordered,
round(sum(item_price),2) as total_item_price,
FROM `order_table` 
where brand = "XYZ" 
and currency = 'USD' 
and sales_channel = 'FakeChannel.com'
and date(purchased_at_PST) between '2021-01-03' and '2021-01-09'

join 
on  date(order_table.purchased_at_PST) = date_table.date_formatted
;
```

The error I get is: Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword JOIN at [15:]

purchased_at_PST is a DATETIME and date_formatted is a DATE field

Comment: 1. you have `join` without specifying the table to join with; 2. `where` clause should be moved to after `from ... join ... on ...` 3. in any case your query makes no much sense so I recommend you to update your questions with details of your case, input data, expected output, logic, etc.

Comment: My mistake, I figured it out.   I needed to do what you said and then name the tables correctly which I did not.

Comment: SELECT 
fiscal_week_of_year,
sum(quantity) as units_ordered,
round(sum(item_price),2) as total_item_price,
FROM `order_table` 

join `date_table`
on  date(`order_table`.purchased_at_PST) = `date_table`.date_formatted
where brand = "XYZ" 
and currency = 'USD' 
and sales_channel = 'FakeChannel.com'
and date(purchased_at_PST) between '2021-01-03' and '2021-01-09'
group by 1 order by 1
;

Comment: It worked after I did the fixes shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning the name of the table that You are going to join with.